# How to visualise and analyse two aphid species direction facing based on orientation of a plant in relation to gravity

Tags: r, data-visualization, biostatistics

I've performed an experiment looking at whether the orientation a plant is held in (upright, sideways or downwards) will effect the behaviour of two aphid species (*S. avenae* and *M. dirhodum*) on whether they prefer to face the base of the plant or the top of the plant at each orientation or whether their orientation is effected by gravity (positive geotaxis = facing the floor no matter plant orientation, negative geotaxis = facing the sky no matter the plant orientation).

There are 5 replicates for each orientation per species, so 30 plants in total, with an intial amount of 10 aphids per plant, however after leaving them for 18 hours the final total varies for each plant due to movement.

The proportion has also been included for root facing (rf) top facing (tf) positive gravitaxis (pg) and negative gravitaxis (ng)

I would like to know how I could visualise comparisons between the two species in addition to comparing the different orientations.

I would also like to know which statistical test I could use (and how) to find out if there is a significant effect on aphid facing direction caused by the plant orientation or whether they face a direction based on gravity instead, including if either species has a preference to face a certain direction

I am using `R` for this work.

here is the `dput` for the data

```
structure(list(tube_num = 1:30, orientation = c("Up", "Up", "Up", 
"Up", "Up", "Sideways", "Sideways", "Sideways", "Sideways", "Sideways", 
"Down", "Down", "Down", "Down", "Down", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", 
"Up", "Sideways", "Sideways", "Sideways", "Sideways", "Sideways", 
"Down", "Down", "Down", "Down", "Down"), aphid_species = c("S.avenae", 
"S.avenae", "S.avenae", "S.avenae", "S.avenae", "S.avenae", "S.avenae", 
"S.avenae", "S.avenae", "S.avenae", "S.avenae", "S.avenae", "S.avenae", 
"S.avenae", "S.avenae", "M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum", 
"M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum", 
"M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum", 
"M.dirhodum", "M.dirhodum"), root_facing = c(3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L), plant_top_facing = c(2L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L), pos_geotaxis = c(3L, 
7L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L), neg_geotaxis = c(2L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L), total_aphids = c(5L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), total_proportion_rf = c(0.6, 
1, 0.833, 0.6, 0.667, 0.5, 0, 0.833, 0.75, 0.75, 0.333, 0.2, 
0.167, 0.75, 0.6, 0.143, 0.5, 0.2, 0.167, 0.182, 0.25, 0, 0.167, 
0.2, 0, 0.286, 0, 0, 0.6, 0), total_proportion_tf = c(0.4, 0, 
0.167, 0.4, 0.333, 0.375, 1, 0.167, 0.25, 0.25, 0.667, 0.8, 0.833, 
0.25, 0.4, 0.857, 0.5, 0.8, 0.833, 0.818, 0.75, 1, 0.833, 0.8, 
1, 0.714, 1, 1, 0.4, 1), total_proportion_pg = c(0.6, 1, 0.833, 
0.6, 0.667, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.833, 0.25, 0.4, 0.143, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.167, 0.182, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.714, 1, 1, 0.4, 1), 
    total_proportion_ng = c(0.4, 0, 0.167, 0.4, 0.333, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.167, 0.75, 0.6, 0.857, 0.5, 0.8, 0.833, 
    0.818, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.286, 0, 0, 0.6, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Comment: Interesting question. Ideally, it would make sense to ask about possible analyses *before* collecting the data.